# Find the painting

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, mystery

A famous painting of Julius Caesar has been stolen from a museum. The thief, being a cryptic lover, has left these clues behind.

“I have left the painting somewhere within the city.”

[image]

The letter found alongside was which is supposed to give the location of the painting.

ZQMDFTQEAGFTNDUPSQ

Can you find out the painting?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To read the... weird thing which seems to part of the letter (?)

> Flip it horizontally:
>  [image]

This alludes to this kind of decoder

> [image]

Move the inner circle so A lines up with M, and we get

> NEARTHESOUTHBRIDGE

So we look there

Comment: Another interesting thing to note: "A famous painting of Julius *Caesar*". This is a hint to Caesar Cipher, which this is.